# ASP.NET MVC AJAX loading a file

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I try to load a file using AJAX, which does NOT work.

View

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = null;
}

<html>
<head>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("button").click(function () {
            $("div").load('test1.txt');
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div><h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2></div>
<button>Change Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

The path to test1.txt is:
~/Views/Ajax/test1.txt

The path to the view is
~/Views/Ajax/Index.cshtml

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your file to `~/Content/test1.txt`. The content path is not affected by MVC routing rules.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("button").click(function () {
            $("div").load('@Url.Content("~/Content/test1.txt")');
        });
    });
</script>
```